# What is the function of "so" in "ich hab so ‘ne Ahnung"?

Tags: adverb

> Ich hab **so** ‘ne Ahnung, da bahnt sich was an.

This is just a wild guess, but I wonder if this "so" is a colloquial device similar to:

> J'ai **comme** une mauvaise impression. (in French)

How does it compare to simply saying:

> Ich hab ‘ne Ahnung, da bahnt sich was an.

Comment: Or in english: "I feel *like* something going down". So there, *so* is perhaps a derivative of "*so ... wie*" and *so* as in *therefore*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amongst the myriads of different meanings and usages of [***so***](https://www.dwds.de/wb/so) we have it used here colloquially as a particle to weaken something or make it vaguely true.

It is a similar usage as in:

> Sie hatte **so** einen (= so eine Art) Zerstäuber in den Hahn einbauen lassen <sup>M. Walser, Halbzeit, 287</sup>

Another, similar usage of **so** to make things vague is often found when giving an approximate number or a time in colloquial speech:

> Es waren so hundert Leute auf der Veranstaltung.
>     Komm' doch so um acht zu uns.
>     Das kostet so um die 5 Euro pro Person.

Answer (score 0):

"so": it's an informal extension.
semantical it points to a specific idea what could happen whereas "Ich hab 'ne Ahnung..." can be interpreted as "I know that something will go on.."

Comment: "Ich hab 'ne Ahnung..." habe ich noch nie gehoert, aber das ist vermutlich auch nur eine Abkuerzung fuer "so eine".

Comment: das kommt auf die Betonung an, denn man könnte "Ahnung" so betonen, dass es suggerieren soll, dass man tatsächlich weiß, dass etwas passieren wird wogegen "so eine" eher auf eine Vermutung hindeutet

Comment: So eine deutet darauf hin, der Addressat wisse wie die Ahnung einzuschaetzen sei. "Eine Ahnung haben" ist eher als Gegenstueck zu "keine Ahnung" zu verstehen. *Keine Ahnung* muss nicht weiter qualifiziert oder eingeschaetzt werden. Eine Ahnung drueckt dann eben nur aus, dass doch qualitative Eigenschaften vorhanden sind. Ansonsten hat man einfach nur Ahnung (unzaehlbar), bzw. die Ahnung (bestimmt). Eben daher sagt man eigentlich auch eher, "ich ahne", bzw. "ich habe *die* Ahnung, da bahnt sich was an", da die Bestimmtheit im Nebensatz folgt.

Comment: Nu wuerd ich auch eher dazu tendieren, "eine bestimmte Ahnung" zu sagen, aber ich behaupte mal, das waer formal falsch, denn wenn ich mehrere widerspruechliche Ahnungen im Hinterkopf haette, waere eben keine davon hinreichend bestimmt. Soetwas wie eine ungefaehre Ahnung ist dagegen nicht besonders sinnvoll, da das schon durch den Begriff in der Umgangssprache schon enthalten ist. Formal darueber zu reden ist dann sowieso unsinnig von mir.